# Example of JavaEE projects

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, spring-data, tdd, business-logic

I'm looking for example of advanced Java project (repo or link). There are a lot of projects with hello world or simple examples but it's not what I'm looking for.

I'd like to get project which contains:

- large business logic and business rules
- modern architecture
- tdd
- spring boot, hiberante or spring-data
- design patterns
- clean code

These hello world examples are useless. I'd like to know how to use tdd, patterns etc among large number of classes and business logic (not yet another CRUD...). I'd like to know how to create objects, how to work with them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to find all from your list in one public repo :-) But maybe you can find at least some in those:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic
- https://github.com/BottegaIT/ddd-leaven-v2
- https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject

As a sidenote, I'm afraid you can't really learn TDD from just reviewing static code. The core of TDD is the habit of starting with a failing test, which you can acquire only by practice, preferably working with an experienced TDD-er.